# Problem storing result from loop calculation in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hi just started javascript last week and enjoying very much....

Taking the advice to experiment to learn and  so I created  this----

The problem I have is that it only returns the first teams scores to the log...

If I comment out console.log (at the bottom) and replace the return statement with console.log it shows all the teams and results as expected - but I wanted to store the result into a variable - any suggestions?

```
const Teams = [
  {
    Team: "Arsenal",
    wins: 3,
    lost: 2,
    draw: 2,
  },

  {
    Team: "Liverpool",
    wins: 5,
    lost: 1,
    draw: 1,
  },

  {
    Team: "Chelsea",
    wins: 3,
    lost: 1,
    draw: 3,
  },

  {
    Team: "Manchester City",
    wins: 13,
    lost: 3,
    draw: 1,
  },

  {
    Team: "Leicester City",
    wins: 4,
    lost: 3,
    draw: 2,
  },
];

const results = function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < Teams.length; i++) {
    return `${Teams[i].Team} have ${Teams[i].wins} wins- with ${
      Teams[i].draw
    } draws and ${Teams[i].lost} loses. The total anount of points are: ${
      Teams[i].wins * 3 + (Teams[i].lost = 0) + Teams[i].draw * 1
    }`;
  }
};
console.log(results());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thing is that

1. you don't store the values in any variable, you return it in your code.
2. return will break the loop on the first instance, which is 0 in your case.

Herein, the most popular (not the shortest, but most clear way) is to store in variable. And return it after the loop ends. I'd prefer to store in array.

```
const results = function () {
let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Teams.length; i++) {
    result.push(`${Teams[i].Team} have ${Teams[i].wins} wins- with ${
      Teams[i].draw
    } draws and ${Teams[i].lost} loses. The total anount of points are: ${
      Teams[i].wins * 3 + (Teams[i].lost = 0) + Teams[i].draw * 1
    }`);
  }
return result;
};
console.log(results());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the loop to be completed, you are actually skiping the loop, something like:

```
const results = function () {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Teams.length; i++) {
    result.push(`
      ${Teams[i].Team} have ${Teams[i].wins} wins- with ${
        Teams[i].draw
      } draws and ${Teams[i].lost} loses. The total anount of points are: ${
        Teams[i].wins * 3 + (Teams[i].lost = 0) + Teams[i].draw * 1
      }`
    ); 
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(results());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you come to a return, it will stop to do anything after it and returns and exists the function, so it only returns the first one. you could just console log in the loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for using `map()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

For example:

```
const results = Teams.map(team => {
  return `${team.Team} have ${team.wins} wins- ` +
    `with ${team.draw} draws and ${team.lost} losses. ` +
    `The total points are: ${(team.wins * 3) + (team.draw)}`
});
```

The map() function transforms (maps) each of the elements in the source array (`Teams`) to a new value and stores the new values in a new array assigned to `results`.